# Converting coordinates to something understandable for AutoCAD

Tags: coordinates, autocad, autocad-map, title, philippines

I got this from a title and need to convert it and use it in AutoCAD with coordinates. Is there anyone who can tell me how to do this?

BEGINNING AT A POINT MARKED "1" ON PLAN, 
BEING S. 29 DEG. 29’W., 1792.86 M. FROM BLLM NO. 1, ANTIPOLO CADASTRE; THENCE 
THENCE S. 85 DEG. 56'E., 21.00 M. TO POINT 2; 
THENCE S. 4-DEG. 04'W., 12.00 M. TO POINT 3; 
THENCE N. 85 DEG. 56'W., 21.00 M. TO POINT 4; 
THENCE N.4 DEG. 04'E., 12.00 M. TO THE POINT OF BEGINNING,

Comment: Looks like a traverse description to me. You need to know where the benchmark point is before you can do any real work.

Comment: if we forget about the begin point, is there anyway we can use this to use the rest to draw it in Autocad?

S. 85 DEG. 56'E., 21.00 M. TO S. 4-DEG. 04'W 
S. 4-DEG. 04'W., 12.00 M. TO N. 85 DEG. 56'W
N. 85 DEG. 56'W., 21.00 M. TO N.4 DEG. 04'E 
N.4 DEG. 04'E., 12.00 M. TO 85 DEG. 56'E

Comment: It seems quite likely that it could be done, but GIS SE is more about Focused question/Best answer compilation than tutorials.  See the [Tour] for more information on how we operate.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Adam.

If your intended use only requires accurately drawing the quadrilateral defined by points 1,2,3,4, and then I assume placing other objects you're working on relative to it, then all you really need is to look up in Autocad how to specify an object (polyline?) using azimuth and distance. (It's been a while since I used AutoCad and it may depend on what version you have, so won't give instructions on that).

Azimuth is measured as an angle from a fixed direction. Based on implementation, it may be clockwise from North or counterclockwise from East (you can check what applies in your implementation). If it's clockwise from north, `S. 85 DEG. 56'E.` sounds like azimuth would be 180 degrees - (85 degrees 56 minutes) so 180-85-56/60=94.0666667 degrees, so point 2 would be 21 m distance along this azimuth from point 1 etc. Ditto for the rest.

At your scale (21 and 12 metres), if that quadrilateral is all you need, you don't need fancy geospatial features, just this CAD distance/azimuth specification.

If you do need to precisely position point 1 versus the survey marker 1793m further away, then you need to be more careful. You'll probably want GIS software with some sort of basemap, or an aerial image or map georeferenced, to identify where the survey marker is, and then place point 1 relative to it. At this point, the image/map projection may start to matter, as may compass direction inclination drift over time.