# Mapping points in PRS92

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, philippines

I am assisting on a project in the Philippines to map some areas. I've been given a sheet the has points, but its unlike anything I've seen before and have no idea how to put it in a format that would allow me to upload it into QGIS.

A brief example of what I am working with is like this:

"Beginning at a point mark '1' on Protected Area Boundary Map, being N 49-11-05 E, 5,221.294 meters from BHL-No.3080 (PRS 92 Control point: Latitude 09-57-30.57, Longitude 123-57-19.69) of the Tubigon, Province Bohol

`Thence          N 81-30-40 E     203.226     m. to corner     2 ;`
 `Thence          S 60-20-27 E     248.566     m. to corner     3 ;`

`Thence          S 47-13-20 E     237.059     m. to corner     4 ;`

and so on and so forth it continues like this until returning to point 1.

Looking for any insight on how to put this in a format in which I can upload these points to QGIS.

Comment: Seems to be related with the following question: [Converting coordinates to something understandable for AutoCAD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348591/converting-coordinates-to-something-understandable-for-autocad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the Earth is flat and that the meridians are parallel. Let's assume also that *BHL-No.3080* point has coordinates *Easting = 0 , Northing = 0*.  We need it to calculate the coordinates of the other points in a planimetric way.

Here we go: We will make a spreadsheet for the calculation of the planimetric coordinates:

[image: 1]

The first row has the field names. The second row has the *BHL-No.3080* point. The values are just to define the type of values expected in the following rows, and *Easting = 0, Northing = 0* coordinates.

In the *degrees* field, we are calculating the angle in decimal degrees with the following formula:

- `=(D3*3600+E3*60+F3)/3600`

In the *az_degrees* field we are applying certain logic to transform the angles to azimuthes (the angle from North, clockwise), with the following formula:

- `=IF(C3="N",IF(G3="E",H3,360-H3),IF(G3="E",180-H3,180+H3))`

Note that we are not handling errors, just looking for *N* or *E* values; if not, we just assume *S* or *W*.

Then, we are converting azimuthes to radians in the *az_radians* field, with the following formula:

- `=RADIANS(I3)`

Finally, we can calculate Eastings and Northings with 2D Euclidean geometry:

- `=K2+SIN(J3)*B3` For the *easting* of point 1,
- `=L2+COS(J3)*B3` For the *northing* of point 1.

Thats all, save it as a CSV file.

```
name,dist,n_s,dd,mm,ss,e_w,degrees,az_degrees,az_radians,easting,northing
BHL-No.3080,0,N,0,0,0,E,0,0,0,0,0
1,5221.294,N,49,11,5,E,49.1847222222222,49.1847222222222,0.8584353444566,3951.58387995458,3412.75488046228
2,203.226,N,81,30,40,E,81.5111111111111,81.5111111111111,1.42263726584782,4152.58343929481,3442.75461747835
3,248.566,S,60,20,27,E,60.3408333333333,119.659166666667,2.08844643852598,4368.58341451516,3319.75434487375
4,237.059,S,47,13,20,E,47.2222222222222,132.777777777778,2.31740939570358,4542.58313963062,3158.75414257343
```

---

Let's create a custom CRS in QGIS. This is a Transverse Mercator transformation method of a PRS92 datum, centered in the geographic coordinates of point *BHL-No.3080*:

`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=9.9584917 +lon_0=123.9554694 +ellps=clrk66 +towgs84=-127.62,-67.24,-47.04,-3.068,4.903,1.578,-1.06 +no_defs`

[image: 2]

And import the points *CSV* file into QGIS with that CRS:

[image: 3]

If they are not there, the geographic coordinates of the *BHL-No.3080* point may be wrong...

[image: 4]